# XSLT: Grouping and sorting....how?

Tags: xslt, xsl-grouping

I have an XML file that looks like the following...

```
    <states>
 <state>
  <name>North Carolina</name>
  <city>Charlotte</city>
 </state>
 <state>
  <name>Alaska</name>
  <city>Fairbanks</city>
 </state>
 <state>
  <name>Virginia</name>
  <city>Leesburg</city>
 </state>
 <state>
  <name>Alaska</name>
  <city>Coldfoot</city>
 </state>
 <state>
  <name>North Carolina</name>
  <city>Harrisburg</city>
 </state>
 <state>
  <name>Virginia</name>
  <city>Ashburn</city>
 </state>  
</states>
```

I need to produce a report that lists each state, is alphabetical order with each city following.... such as ..

```
Alaska - Fairbanks, Coldfoot
North Carolina - Charlotte, Harrisburg
Virginia - Leesburg, Ashburn
```

(the cities do not have to be in alpha order, just the states)

I tried to solve this by doing a for-each on states/state, sorting it by name and processing it.  Like this....

```
    <xsl:for-each select="states/state">
       <xsl:sort select="name" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="name"/>-<xsl:value-of select="city"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

This gave me....

```
 Alaska - Fairbanks
 Alaska - Coldfoot
 North Carolina - Charlotte
 North Carolina - Harrisburg
 Virginia - Leesburg
 Virginia - Ashburn
```

The sorting worked, now I want to group.  The only thing I could think to do was to compare to the previous state, since it is sorted, it should recognize if the state value has not changed.  Like this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="states/state">
             <xsl:sort select="name" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
  <xsl:variable name="name"><xsl:value-of select="name">
  <xsl:variable name="previous-name"><xsl:value-of select="(preceding-sibling::state)/name">
  <xsl:if test="$name != $previous-name">
   <br/><xsl:value-of select="name"/>-
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Sadly, it appears that the preceding-sibling feature does not work well with the sort, so, the first time through (on the first Alaska) it saw the first North Carolina as a preceding sibling.  This causes some weird results, which were not at all to my liking.

So, I am using XSLT1.0... Any thoughts/suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kStateByName" match="state" use="name"/>
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates
                   select="/*/state[count(.|key('kStateByName',name)[1])=1]">
            <xsl:sort select="name"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="state">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name,' - ')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kStateByName',name)/city"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="city">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,substring(', ', 
                                                 1 div (position()!=last())),
                                       substring('&#xA;',
                                                 1 div (position()=last())))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
Alaska - Fairbanks, Coldfoot
North Carolina - Charlotte, Harrisburg
Virginia - Leesburg, Ashburn
```

**Note**: Grouping by State's name. Separator substring expression only works with a pull style (applying templates to city)

An XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="states">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="state" group-by="name">
            <xsl:sort select="name"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(name,
                                         ' - ',
                                         string-join(current-group()/city,', '),
                                         '&#xA;')"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Just for fun, this XPath 2.0 expression:

```
string-join(for $state in distinct-values(/*/*/name)
            return concat($state,
                          ' - ',
                          string-join(/*/*[name=$state]/city,
                                      ', ')),
            '&#xA;')
```

Comment: +1, your the man Alejandro.  The 1.0 solution looks like the Muenchian Method, is that correct?

Comment: @Abe Miessler: You are right. It's the Muenchian Method. It's the standar grouping for XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 1):

For grouping in XSLT 1.0 you are probably going to have to use the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).  It can be hard to understand but once you get it working you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This will return a distinct list of states:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="states/state">
     <xsl:sort select="name" />
     <xsl:if test="not(name = preceding-sibling::state/name)" >
         <xsl:value-of select="name" />
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

I used your example XML, built a little style sheet with the above, ran it through Xalan-j, and it returns:

Alaska
North Carolina
Virginia

So from there you should be able to apply a template or another for-each loop to pull the list of cities for each distinct state.

Chris

Comment: This is the way to go when you have no access to `key` (Long, long ago). But if you take comparison as complexity unit, you will have 1 + (N * N) / 2 complexity. Then you need to process the group. That will be N' * N complexity with node set comparison. Also, that test is not necesary. You could have that test as a predicate added to for-each select expression.